# How to bind click function of a file input to a "v-on" event?

Tags: javascript, dom, vue.js

I trying to write a pretty uploader in Vue.js. I just hide `<input type="file">` element and trigger click function while mdl-button is clicked.

Following code is my implementation.

template:

```
<form method="post" action="#" @submit.prevent="">
  <input id="fileInput" type="file">
  <mdl-button type="submit" @click="onClick" colored raised>
    <span>Upload</span>
  </mdl-button>
</form>
```

script:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      filePath: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onClick: function (e) {
      document.getElementById('fileInput').click()
    }
  }
}
```

style:

```
#fileInput {
  display: none;
}
```

We can notice that `document.getElementById` is not Vue-style.

How about binding fileInput's click function to mdl-button's click event?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply turn your `mdl-button` into a `<label>` tag. That would make it semantically more valuable and accessible as well:

```
<form method="post" action="#" @submit.prevent="">
  <input id="fileInput" type="file">
  <mdl-button type="submit" colored raised>
    <label for="fileInput">Upload</label>
  </mdl-button>
</form>
```

I'm not sure what kind of markup your `<mdl-button>` component contains, but you might just want to replace whatever you use as the button element with the `<label>` element.

Comment: Only works when you click on the label. Click on the mdl-button, file selection window doesn't pop up.

Comment: Well yes, as I wrote, you would probably need to replace the base element of `<mdl-button>` with a label. Since I don't know what `mdl-button` looks like, I don't know if that is possible…